# Adding traditional events to a custom control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have been trying to figure this out with lots of googling and SO, but unfortunately I cannot solve this issue. The more I read, the more confused I get.

I would like to build an autocomplete textbox as a custom control.

My CustomControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApplicationStyling.Controls.AutoCompleteTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationStyling.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="AutoCompleteBox">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
                 Style="{DynamicResource InputBox}"
                 x:Name="SearchBox"
                 Text="{Binding Text}"
                 TextChanged="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=TextChanged}"/>

        <ListBox x:Name="SuggestionList"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteTextBox, Path=SuggestionsSource}"
                 SelectionChanged="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=SelectionChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Label}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace ApplicationStyling.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AutoCompleteTextBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AutoCompleteTextBox : UserControl
    {
           
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuggestionsSourceProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;

        // Events
        public static readonly RoutedEvent TextChangedProperty;
        public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectionChangedProperty;


        static AutoCompleteTextBox()
        {
            // Attributes
            AutoCompleteTextBox.SuggestionsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SuggestionsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox));
            AutoCompleteTextBox.TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox));

            // Events
            AutoCompleteTextBox.TextChangedProperty = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TextChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox));
            AutoCompleteTextBox.SelectionChangedProperty = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SelectionChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox));

        }

        #region Events
        public event RoutedEventHandler TextChanged
        {
            add { AddHandler(TextChangedProperty, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(TextChangedProperty, value); }
        }

        // This method raises the Tap event
        void RaiseTextChangedEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(AutoCompleteTextBox.TextChangedProperty);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }



        public event RoutedEventHandler SelectionChanged
        {
            add { AddHandler(SelectionChangedProperty, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(SelectionChangedProperty, value); }
        }

        // This method raises the Tap event
        void RaiseSelectionChangedEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(AutoCompleteTextBox.SelectionChangedProperty);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }

        #endregion

        #region DProperties
        /// <summary>
        /// IEnumerable ItemsSource Property for the Suggenstion Box
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable SuggestionsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (IEnumerable)GetValue(AutoCompleteTextBox.SuggestionsSourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(AutoCompleteTextBox.SuggestionsSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the Text attribute which routes to the Textbox
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(AutoCompleteTextBox.TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(AutoCompleteTextBox.TextProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public AutoCompleteTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SearchBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) => RaiseTextChangedEvent();
            SuggestionList.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) => RaiseSelectionChangedEvent();
        }


    }
}
```

And lastly, the way I use it:

```
<asc:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="ShareAutoCompleteBox"
                                 Grid.Row="3"
                                 SelectionChanged="ShareAutoCompleteBox_SelectionChanged"
                                 TextChanged="ShareAutoCompleteBox_TextChanged"/>
```

where `asc` is the namespace for the outsourced class library which is loaded via app.xaml.

Anyways, the issues I am getting in the XAML at the `TextBox.TextChanged` attribute, and when running the code:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.

So what exactly is going on here? I would like to forward the `AutoCompleteTextBox TextChanged` to the `TextBox` within the Custom Control Template. Same with the `SelectionChanged` to the `Listbox`.

I took most of the code from either https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288(v=vs.100).aspx (for the events) and from some other SO questions the code for the custom properties.

Not sure, what the problem is and I am looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is happening because you are trying to bind the value of the `TextChanged` field to an attribute that expects a method reference. It's *really* confusing to WPF. :)

Just remove the `TextChanged` attribute from the `TextBox` element in your XAML:

```
TextChanged="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=TextChanged}"
```

You already subscribe to the event in your constructor, which is enough. If you do want to use the `TextChanged` attribute *instead* of subscribing in the constructor, then you can do that, but you need to provide an actual event handler, e.g. a method in the code-behind. That method would just call the `RaiseTextChangedEvent()` method, just as your current event handler does. It's just that it would be a named method in the class instead of an anonymous method declared in the constructor.

Same thing applies to the other event.

That said, you might reconsider implementing the forwarded events at all. Typically, your control's `Text` property would be bound to the property of some model object, which can itself react appropriately when that bound property changes. It shouldn't need a separate event on the `UserControl` object to tell it that its value has changed.